# How do I make the physics more natural?

Tags: animation, physics, procedural

Don't ask why but this is a cube shaped egg. The egg is cracking and something is popping out. No matter how I play with the mass, force and deleting bakes and rebaking, it doesn't change what it's doing. I just want the pieces to pop up a little and fall to the side. I tried to change the force from 1 to .1 and it blows the pieces out even farther.

Gif:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jfhMj.jpg

File download:

https://filebin.net/7d7fq23a1r6syqku

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you don't know how things work, it is a good idea to delete some things to exclude the cause of it.

E.g. if you delete the force (and delete your bake) you will see - the parts are not moving because of your force.

They are moving because they overlap and their origin isn't in the right place.

You can prove that by...

1. delete your rigid body cache
2. select all your parts > objects -> set origin to geometry
3. set to individual origins -> move a bit up and scale them down
4. set collision margin to 0

then it looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Ok that's a good start. Thank you!